# Home Screen, Recent apps, pull down menu not working multi user nexus 6

Tags: 7.0-nougat, multi-user, nexus-6, recents-screen, home-button

Hi two days ago my phone shutdown due to low battery, charged it and powered it on. With the power on came all the issues listed below:

- can not switch users (have three user accounts created each with their apps)
- home and recent buttons do not work, but i hear the haptic when pressed except nothing happens.
- pull down menu does not pull down completely: only displays a few icons and thats about it.
- can not switch to debug mode, can not connect to pc.

I have seen similar issues over the internet and looked for over 18 hours but so far none has worked. the ones i have tried are:

- Downloaded the Nova launcher app but doesnt work for me as there is
  no *SetupWizardTestActivity*. i have one activity and that is the
  *carrierSetupActivity* or the name is similar to that.
- tried the *Navigation bar and Activity Launcher apps*.
- Tried *wiping the cache* and *rebooting in safe mode*

If possible I do not want to factory reset the phone, but if there is no other alternative. Then ***it will be very helpful*** if someone can tell me

> how to back up the accounts data for all the three users and how best
>   I can retrieve it after the reset. Also how to switch the user for the time being so that i can at least manually back up information from other users - if there is a way.

All suggestions are welcome. thank you all in advance. Am using the nexus 6 running android 7.1.1